# The difference between farmed and non-farmed sardines

Tags: diet, fish

I found the following post on a food-related forum ([here](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/forum/thread10121.html#post141067)):

> Farmed fish do have omega 3 in them. They have a chunk of omega 6 too
>   so while they do have omega 3, they're not ideal for normalizing the
>   ratio. However there is a case in which sardine flesh is being sold
>   after the omega 3 has been extracted to make sardine oil. A good rule
>   of thumb is that the saturated fat should be about a quarter or less
>   of of the total fat if the tin doesn't specifically say that it has
>   omega 3. If saturated fat is a higher percentage of the sardine, the
>   omega 3 has been removed.

Does "farmed sardines" mean that they are being grown in closed pools (which would be strange since I heard sardines are generally caught in the open seas.

Is there a way to distinguish between farmed and non-farmed sardines?